# Best way to encapsulate creation logic

Tags: c#, architecture, repository

I think I have an amateur architecture question, but this is something that I've been struggling to figure out for quite a while.

I have a C# web project that creates users in several places like this:

```
var user = /*create user somehow*/;
_userRepository.Add(user);
_userRepository.SaveChanges();
```

Now I need to add logic that sends email notifications every time a user is created:

```
var user = /*create user somehow*/;
_userRepository.Add(user);
_userRepository.SaveChanges();
_notificationService.SendUserCreatedNotification(user);
```

The problem with this is I wouldn't like to add the same line of code to all the places where new user is created (DRY!).

Now, I could wrap up the Add/Save/SendUserCreatedNotification logic in a separate service:

```
var user = /*create user somehow*/;
_userCreationService.AddAndSave(user);
```

But:

- the purpose of this service would be logically weird (add user to
  repo, save changes to repo, send notifications); I can't even think
  of a good name for this service & method
- The service method would only have 3 lines of code: Add/Save/SendUserCreatedNotification

How do you usually solve such tasks? Is approach 2 the best way to go? Or maybe there exists a better approach 3?

Comment: Can you not have it done at the database level through a combination of triggers / stored procedure ?

Comment: probs best asked on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ but you should look at events, when a user is created you can trigger a UserCreateEvent and other parts of your code can subscribe to that and send welcome emails etc.

Comment: Help me understand why you can't do this in the Add(user) method for your repository.

Comment: @ToddCopeland, it's a separation of concerns. A repository is always an object that has a sole purpose of saving/loading data. It should only depend on the storage mechanism (DB, ORM). It should not send any notifications or have dependencies on email clients.

Comment: Firing an event is not a dependency.  Something else is either there to listen to it or not... Same with data stored in a table if you prefer.  Overload your method as Add(user myUser, bool FireEmailEvent) and change Add(user) to call Add(user, true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to send this notification from the `_userRepository.SaveChanges();` method.
You would check your UoW change tracker for all the user entities that are in the 'Created' state and send these notifications after committing.

However, using this approach, the notification sending will be hidden in your infrastructure/data access/... layer. This means the notification sending logic will not be part of your domain/core logic. For someone to become aware of this part of the logic, they would have to dive into the implementation details of your repository (or UoW).

Instead, you could **fire an event** from the `_userRepository.SaveChanges();` and subscribe to that event in your core logic.

The approach I would take would be the following:

- In `_userRepository.SaveChanges();` for every created user, fire a `UserCreatedEvent` event that will contain the information about the user.
- Subscribe to that event in your core logic and call `_notificationService.SendUserCreatedNotification(user);` from the event handler.

This way, you would also decouple your user creation logic from the notification sending logic.